# AVPlayer status is updated when app comes to foreground

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm building a music player in my iOS app, using `AVPlayer`. I listen to changes for the `AVPlayer.status` property like this, to know when audio is ready to be played:

```
player.currentItem!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: .New, context: nil)
```

And when the status is `.ReadyToPlay` I automatically start playback:

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if (keyPath == "status") {
            if let currentItem = self.player?.currentItem {
                let status = currentItem.status
                if (status == .ReadyToPlay) {                    
                    self.play()
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Works great. The problem, however, is that if I start playing music in my app, pause the music and then leave the app and start playing music in, for example, Spotify, the `AVPlayer`'s status property seems to be changed to `.ReadyToPlay` again the next time my app comes to the foreground, which causes the observer to fire, which in turn causes the music to start playing again.

I assume that something happens with the AVPlayer instance when the app gets focus again, which causes the status property to change/refresh.

How do I prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like expected behavior. If you want to ensure that you only begin playback the first time the `AVPlayerItem` status changes, remove the observer after calling `play()`.

One caveat here is that you should already be removing the observer when the `currentItem` is changed on the player, so you will need to use an additional flag to track whether you are observing the existing `currentItem`.

The owner of the player would keep track of state

```
var isObservingCurrentItem = false
```

And update/check that state when you add the observer

```
if currentItem = player.currentItem where isObservingCurrentItem {
    currentItem.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath:"status")
}

player.currentItem!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: .New, context: nil)
isObservingCurrentItem = true
```

Then you can safely remove the observer once the player is ready to play

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {

    if let object = object,
        keyPath = keyPath,
        currentItem = self.player?.currentItem,
        status = currentItem.status
        where status == .ReadyToPlay {
            self.play()
            object.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath:keyPath)
            isObservingCurrentItem = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I ended up doing a check in observeValueForKeyPath to see if the old and new value were the same (i.e. ReadyToPlay) and if so doing nothing. But your solution is probably better :)

Comment: @chrisH thanks a lot, this helped weird UI issues on app background/foreground sequence. I was missing "remove the observer once the player is ready to play" part - you saved my day